# I want to be notified when a Wordpress user is inactive for more than 2 days

Tags: wordpress

How can I set a rule to notify me by e-mail when a user in my Wordpress website is inactive for more that 2 days or did not visit specific pages?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you it set up at the moment to keep a record of when a user visits the website and what pages they have visited?

Comment: By "inactive", do you just mean the last time they logged in to the WP dashboard?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. Only front-end users, I want to be notified in case they don't visit my website or interact in any way. That way I can try to figure out if I they had any problem.